# Weird white box appears with CSS animations in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

So i'm trying to use this CSS slider and it works perfect in IE and firefox, but not for chrome. When the first image loads it looks normal but when the second image has filled the box i get a white box in the bottom of the page. [Image](http://gyazo.com/e8232822358b94d4e6e5970a8fa82056)

I found this code at [Pure CCS3 Cycling Slideshow](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/) but this problem occurred when i tried to customize it for my school project.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
                     <div id="mask">
                     <ul>
                     <li id="first" class="firstanimation">
                     <a href="#"> <img src="images/turtleSlider/tur1.jpg" alt="Turtle"/> </a>
                     <div class="tooltip"> <h1>Turtle</h1> </div>
                     </li>

                     <li id="second" class="secondanimation">
                     <a href="#"> <img src="images/turtleSlider/tur2.jpg" alt="Turtle"/> </a>
                     <div class="tooltip"> <h1>My Dad Tomas & A Turtle</h1> </div>
                     </li>

                     <li id="third" class="thirdanimation">
                     <a href="#"> <img src="images/turtleSlider/tur3.jpg" alt="Turtle"/> </a>
                     <div class="tooltip"> <h1>Turtle</h1> </div>
                     </li>

                     <li id="fourth" class="fourthanimation">
                     <a href="#"> <img src="images/turtleSlider/tur4.jpg" alt="Turtle"/> </a>
                     <div class="tooltip"> <h1>Me & A Turtle</h1> </div>
                     </li>

                     <li id="fifth" class="fifthanimation">
                     <a href="#"> <img src="images/turtleSlider/tur5.jpg" alt="Turtle"/> </a>
                     <div class="tooltip"> <h1>Turtle</h1> </div>
                     </li>
                     </ul>

                     </div>
                     <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

CSS:

```
html{ 
  background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body{
    font-family:"Open Sans", serif;
    margin: 30px 15% 20px 15%;
    min-width: 1010px;
}

    #slider {
   border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   height: 500px;
   width: 667px;
   overflow: visible;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
#mask {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 500px;
}
#slider ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
}
#slider li {
   width: 667px;  /* Width Image */
   height: 500px; /* Height Image */
   position: absolute;
   top: -505px; /* Original Position - Outside of the Slider */
   list-style: none;
}
#slider li.firstanimation {
   -webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
   animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.secondanimation {
   -webkit-animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
   animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.thirdanimation {
   -webkit-animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
   animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.fourthanimation {
   -webkit-animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
   animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.fifthanimation {
   -webkit-animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
   animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    4%  { top:0px; }
    16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    20% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    21% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    50% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    92% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    96% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }

}
@-webkit-keyframes cycletwo {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    16% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    20% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    24% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    36% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    40% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    41% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }  
    100%{ top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclethree {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    36% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    40% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    44% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    56% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    60% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    61% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclefour {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    56% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    60% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    64% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    76% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    80% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    81% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclefive {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    76% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    80% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    84% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    96% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    100%{ top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cycle {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    4%  { top:0px; } 
    16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    20% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    21% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    92% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    96% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cycletwo {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    16% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    20% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    24% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    36% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    40% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    41% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; } 
    100%{ top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclethree {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    36% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    40% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    44% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    56% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
    60% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    61% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; } 
    100%{ top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclefour {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    56% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    60% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    64% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    76% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    80% { top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    81% { top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    100%{ top:-505px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclefive {
    0%  { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    76% { top:-505px; opacity:0; }
    80% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    84% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
    96% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
    100%{ top:505px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
}
@keyframes cycle {
   0%  { top: 0px; } /* When you start the slide, the first image is already visible */
   4%  { top: 0px; } /* Original Position */
   16% { top: 0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } /* From 4% to 16 % = for 3 seconds the image is visible */
   20% { top: 505px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 16% to 20% = for 1 second exit image */
   21% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; } /* Return to Original Position */
   92% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   96% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; } /* From 96% to 100% = for 1 second enter image*/
   100%{ top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes cycletwo {
   0%  { top: -505px; opacity: 0; } /* Original Position */
   16% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; }/* Starts moving after 16% to this position */
   20% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   24% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }  /* From 20% to 24% = for 1 second enter image*/
   36% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }   /* From 24% to 36 % = for 3 seconds the image is visible */
   40% { top: 505px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 36% to 40% = for 1 second exit image */
   41% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }   /* Return to Original Position */
   100%{ top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes cyclethree {
   0%  { top: -505px; opacity: 0; }
   36% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; }
   40% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   44% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   56% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   60% { top: 505px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   61% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   100%{ top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes cyclefour {
   0%  { top: -505px; opacity: 0; }
   56% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; }
   60% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   64% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   76% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   80% { top: 505px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   81% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   100%{ top: -505px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes cyclefive {
   0%  { top: -505px; opacity: 0; }
   76% { top: -505px; opacity: 0; }
   80% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   84% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   96% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   100%{ top: 505px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
}
.progress-bar {
   position: relative;
   top: -5px;
   width: 750px;
   height: 5px;
   background: #000;
   -webkit-animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
   -moz-animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
   animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fullexpand {
   0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width: 0%; opacity: 0; }
   4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width: 0%; opacity: 0.3; }
   16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width: 100%; opacity: 0.7; }
   17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width: 100%; opacity: 0.3; }
   18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fullexpand {
   0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width: 0%; opacity: 0; }
   4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width: 0%; opacity: 0.3; }
   16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width: 100%; opacity: 0.7; }
   17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width: 100%; opacity: 0.3; }
   18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fullexpand {
   /* In these keyframes, the progress-bar is stationary */
   0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width: 0%; opacity: 0; }

   /* In these keyframes, the progress-bar starts to come alive */
   4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width: 0%; opacity: 0.3; }

   /* In these keyframes, the progress-bar moves forward for 3 seconds */
   16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width: 100%; opacity: 0.7; }

   /* In these keyframes, the progress-bar has finished his path */
   17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width: 100%; opacity: 0.3; }

   /* In these keyframes, the progress-bar will disappear and then resume the cycle */
   18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
#slider:hover .progress-bar {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
   animation-play-state: paused;
}
#slider .tooltip {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   width: 300px;
   height: 60px;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 75px;
   left: -320px;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#slider .tooltip h1 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: 300;
   line-height: 60px;
   padding: 0 0 0 10px;
   text-align: Right;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
#slider li#first:hover .tooltip,
#slider li#second:hover .tooltip,
#slider li#third:hover .tooltip,
#slider li#fourth:hover .tooltip,
#slider li#fifth:hover .tooltip {
   left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a css definitions for body and html tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added some credits at the bottom as a `<footer>` and now it doesn't show up anymore. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your CSS file:

```
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

This white rectangle is an empty space on the page because document does not cover whole view-port.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Any other suggestions? @PawełPsztyć

Edit: Or it does change it so it looks like it work but a scroll bar appears instead and when you scroll down the same box is there, but its height is smaller.